# Transmiting a parameter in multiplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am working on a Unity 2D fps multiplayer game. Whenever a player presses Space they instantiate a bullet and when a bullet hits any player it has to destroy itself and push the player in the bullet direction. My code looks like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (isServer == false)
        return;
    if (col.gameObject.tag != "bullet")
        return;

    CmdTrigger(col.gameObject);
}

[Command]
void CmdTrigger(GameObject col)
{
    RpcTrigger(col);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcTrigger(GameObject col)
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    rb = col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if (rb.velocity.x > 0)
        RpcExplode(Mathf.Sign(1));
    else
        RpcExplode(Mathf.Sign(-1));

    //Network.Destroy(col); 
}
```

The problem is that when a bullet collides a player I can't transmit well the GameObject to the other players so every player can destroy the bullet on their client. When a bullet hits a player it doesn't destroy itself, it just passes through and the Console shows me this error: "NullRefrenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object", and if I click on it, it brings me to this line:

```
rb = col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

Here is my character control full code: https://pastebin.com/L1DEmQv1

Any ideas? It is very important for me to fix it as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: You only can pass `GameObject` as parameter if this object has a `NetworkIdentity` are you sure that the collider is attached to exactly the same `GameObject` as the `NetworkIdentity`?

Comment: Also note that you may not call `RpcExplode` from client side, only from a server so it makes no sense calling it inside of another `ClientRpc` which is executed on clients

Comment: I verified, both the player prefab and bullet prefab that I use and they have NetworkIdentity and the collider to the same GameObject. I edited it a little to solve the ClientRpc problem.. It is still not working. Any ideeas what should I edit?   https://pastebin.com/KhW1LuKB

Comment: how did you spawn that bullet exactly? apparently it is `null` so not found on the client side.